# How to highlight an entire row based on a cell value using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

I want to highlight the entire row based on the value I get from that if conditional

Comment: Have a look at `df.style` and return with more detailed question if you have any problem. This question as is would get closed soon.

Comment: When posing a question, please include the relevant code directly in the post instead of posting images. Images cannot be search, and may not be visible to some users, such as those who use screen readers.